# NHiberante 2 columns CustomType Invalid SQL

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, datetimeoffset

I was trying to map DateTimeOffset to Oracle type "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" but had no luck.

Then I decided to write a CustomType that uses two columns (first one is a UTC Date field another is TimeZone offset in minutes, number). Oracle SQL generated is something like this:

```
select *
from TIME_EVENTS timeevent0_ 
where (
    timeevent0_.TIME_STAMP_UTC ge TIMESTAMP '2017-07-04 00:00:00.00' /* :p0 */ and
    timeevent0_.TIME_STAMP_TZ ge 0 /* :p1 */)
```

- I have 2 questions here

  - why **ge** is generated insted of >=.  ge is not a valid Oracle function
  - Is it possible for the LINQ

> ```
>    _unitOfWork.For<TimeEvent>().Where(x=>x.MyCustomDateWithOffset >= Date.Now()
> ```

to specify in CustomType that SQL should look like this

```
select *
from TIME_EVENTS timeevent0_ 
where (
    timeevent0_.TIME_STAMP_UTC >= TIMESTAMP '2017-07-04 00:00:00.00' /* :p0 */ and
    timeevent0_.TIME_STAMP_TZ = 0 /* :p1 */)
```

I would like for the second parameter to be equal (=), not grater or equal (>=). Just the first parameter should be >=.

Session factory

```
case "ORACLE":
    return OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
        .AdoNetBatchSize(100)
        .ConnectionString(
            string.Format("User >Id= {0};Password={1};Data Source={2}",
                credentialStore.UserName, credentialStore.Password,?
                credentialStore.DataSource));
```

NHibernate version: 4.0.0.4000
Fluent version: 2.0.3.0

Help appreciated. Regards Simon

Comment: Can you add your session factory config?

Comment: Added session factory to the main question

Comment: It seems to be not supported, check Oskar Berggren comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642298/nhibernate-translates-into-ge-and-throws-genericadoexception-on-object-with-c

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single column custom type. With multiple columns types, only equals is supported and can yield consistent results. Other comparison are not supported: with two columns representing the same value, applying `>` to both columns is in most cases just non-sens. NHibernate has no way to know how to do such a comparison in a meaningful way, so it is not supported.

About using the single column custom type, it should convert between .Net `DateTimeOffset` and Oracle `OracleTimeStampTZ`. The Oracle data provider seems to support only that specific type. See [this question](/q/9471940/1178314). The OP states he had succeeded doing this, but unfortunately he has not shared his code.

About your second question, please do not ask multiple questions. But well, I do not think it is doable with your multiple column custom type anyway. That is just specific.